# What does "/.." mean within a path name?

Tags: macos, filepath

I'm learning Django at the moment, using a Mac with Mountain Lion. There's an absolute path like this:

```
/Users/raghavkumar/Documents/Python_docs/rango/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/..
```

Now what does the `/..` at the very end signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the parent directory of the second `tango_with_django_project` directory, which is

```
/Users/raghavkumar/Documents/Python_docs/rango/tango_with_django_project
```

There are two entries in every directory:

```
.
..
```

These are the current directory and the parent directory.

Note that symlinks can confuse things; see the [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) command and the `-P` and `-L` options for some instances of how they can cause trouble.